# What's the difference between an MTA and SMTP server?

Tags: linux, smtp, mail-transport-agent

Take postfix for example. It's an MTA, but is it also an SMTP server? Are all MTAs SMTP servers? Are any? Is there a difference between a mail transport agent and a mail transfer agent?

Can an MTA be configured to be an SMTP server, or vice versa? What's the difference between an MTA and an SMTP server?

Comment: just try to read wikipedia: Within the Internet email system, a message transfer agent or mail transfer agent (MTA) or mail relay is software that transfers electronic mail messages from one computer to another using SMTP. MTA is a architectural term. SMTP is the technology used by it.

Answer (score 5):

An MTA is a part of an SMTP server; it is responsible for receiving emails from an [MSA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_submission_agent) and then forwarding them to an MDA (if the destination of these e-mails is local) or to another SMTP server.
Some people call MTA an SMTP server.

Answer (score 3):

*Something about [flanker12x's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/530381/20140)  doesn't seem quite right.  Especially because [wikipedia describes postfix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postfix_(software)) as an MTA.*

### Common description

As suggested by @roaima, it's mostly okay to think of an SMTP server as an MTA that receives and sends email over the [SMTP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol).

MTA's that do not *support* SMTP are rare.  So its hard to find an MTA that is not also an SMTP server.

### Pedantic description

MTA's usually have an SMTP server component:

- "MTA" Refers to software which accepts email and routes it towards it's destination (possibly passing it to another MTA).  So an MTA accepts emails and decides where to send them.
- "SMTP server" refers to software which implements the server side of the SMTP protocol.  The server side is exclusively responsible for receiving and accepting emails.

It's acceptable to describe the single piece of software as both an MTA and an SMTP server.  But if you are being really really pedantic, then the SMTP server is just the listening component of the MTA.

The two concepts can even exist separately...

### Not all SMTP servers are MTAs

Some software can have an SMTP server component without being an MTA.  For example: issue tracking software or blog software might allow users to send email responses to threads.  That software might have an SMTP server to receive the responses... **But** the email is immediately processed and discarded.  It's not an MTA because it destructively processes the email.

### Must an MTA have an SMTP server?

*This might be contentious but* I'd say "no"; not necessarily.

Theoretically MTAs can transfer emails between each other by any protocol, as long as the email arrives.  So an MTA is certainly allowed to accept email from other protocols.  As long as an MTA can get an email to its destination, the protocol is irrelevant.

To demonstrate my point, Microsoft Exchange Server can send emails between accounts in the same organisation without using SMTP.  It is still acting as an MTA in this context.  Exchange Server does of course also *have* an SMTP server but it's not theoretically required.

Likewise postfix has multiple components defined in `master.cf` and the SMTP server can be disabled.  As long as you replace it with something, postfix could remain defined as an MTA as long as the user agents can ultimately place email in its queues.

---

SMTP is already [nearly 40 years old](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc821).  We're unlikely to see big rise in MTAs without SMTP any time soon.

Comment: I'd say that SMTP is a protocol for transferring messages between MTAs. They don't need to use SMTP (and indeed in your example with Exchange they don't). By definition, therefore, an SMTP Server is an MTA that can send and/or receive messages using SMTP

Comment: @roaima I'm still mulling over this wording.  The example that bites is ticket software or forum software (Jira?) having the ability to email a response to a thread.  This software might have an SMTP server but wouldn't really be an MTA because of the way it destructively processes the email.

Comment: I think it comes down to the question of whether or not an MTA "_must_" or "_should_" queue and retry

Comment: I’m in love with the quality of this answer - thanks for bein a fren